# How to get the value of the past two bars in pinescript v5?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

So, how can I get the value of the last bars on the candle-stick chart?
I want to confront the value of the past candles with the value of an ema, on the graph or with the actual values to check if it goes over or under the line. Same with two emas, how can I get their value in past bars that already has past?

I tried to search online and found about the "barstate.islastconfirmedhistory", witch didn't really work for me, or maybe I did not fully understand it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the history referencing operator. This will give you the opening prices for the previous two bars.

```
yesterdayOpen = open[1]
dayBeforeOpen = open[2]
```